# OnLocationChanged vs. AddProximityAlert

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

I have read the documentation about both methods but could not figure out what the fundamental difference between the two is.
I understand that AddProximityAlert is being called every 4 minutes, while OnLocationChanged gives us more flexibility of time intervals.
Other than that, is there any difference, in accuracy for example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The two methods serve different purposes. Proximity alerts can be used - as the name suggest - to be alerted when entering or leaving the proximity of something. For example you can set a proximity alert to "Deep Shit" and than an alert will go off when you are in "Deep Shit", or once you're no longer "Deep Shit". But until than nothing will happen, you can go around, get in "Trouble" for example, but as long as you are not in "Deep Shit", alert won't fire.

On the other hand, OnLocationChange gets fired if you move a given distance.

If you are in "Deep Shit" and set a 100m proximity alert, and an on location change listener for 100m, both will get fired. But if you continue going, onLocationChange will fire every 100 meters.

Comment: Well, you don't have accuracy for either alerts. Framework uses the same location information for both, and based on the threshold you set, the location information available and the accuracy of the location information, decides to fire or not fire the event. I don't think that there is a confidence level that you can retrieve.